# Navigate to another charms settings link from the flyout

Tags: windows, winjs

I have created a settings page in the charm and now inside the settings page I have kept a hyperlink and on click of that I need to navigate on to a new flyout link in the charms list. Like I have 2 links in the Charms, - Settings and Help.

From Settings I have to navigate to Help from a hyperlink,

I have tried :

WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.showSettings("helpDiv", "pages/help/help.html");

This does not navigate.

Is it possible to navigate from one flyout to another in Charms - Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you have a matching commandid in the help.html with title in settings.html page(assuming you have help link here) 
below code  should be in settings.html

`WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
        e.detail.applicationcommands = { "helpDiv": { title: "Help", 
            href: "pages/help/help.html" } };
        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
    };`

below code should be in help.html

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" aria-label="Help settings flyout" 
         data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'Help',width:'wide'}">
........
```